# Xdebug not stopping on breakpoints in VS Code

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to set up Xdebug on a docker container running on Ubuntu 22.04 host. It is not stopping on breakpoints.

Xdebug is correctly installed because in PhpStorm breakpoints are working but not in VS Code

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense para saber los atributos posibles.
    // Mantenga el puntero para ver las descripciones de los existentes atributos.
    // Para más información, visite: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/home/myuser/projects/myproject": "/application"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've added `pathMappings` options in `launch.json` file but it is still not working. Did I missed something?